# "[somebody]'s theme" vs "[somebody] theme" — Saxon genitive dillema

Tags: saxon-genitive

When is it required to use *'s* in phrases like below (examples taken from Wikipedia)?

- James Bond theme
- 007 theme
- Boba Fett motif
- Droids motif
- Yoda's theme
- ...

Are there any rules for eliding Saxon genitive?

How does the situation change if we have *something* instead of *somebody*?

Comment: If you add _The_ in front, it would even become _The Yoda theme_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it as "eliding" anything: there are two different constructions:

> possessive + noun
>
> modifying-noun + noun

The first is mostly limited to animate possessors, and denotes something belonging to or specifically associated with the possessor, whereas the second is not so limited, and denotes a less specific association.

In the cases you have given, either is possible*, with little or no difference in meaning. But sometimes one is impossible, or there is a difference in meaning. So

> 007 theme

Means a theme associated with the idea or the person 007, whereas

> 007's theme

is specifically thinking of 007 as a designation of a person, and specifying a theme associated with that person. Similarly

> James Bond theme

is ambiguous as to whether it means a theme specifically associated with the character of Bond, or more generally associated with the phenomenon (or brand) James Bond.

*At first I didn't think "007's theme" was possible, until I remembered that "007" can refer to the person.