# Why do we write "Fourier's law" but "Soret effect"?

Tags: possessives, writing-style, science, surnames

Can you explain why do we write e.g. Fourier's law, Ohm's law, Newton's law of cooling, etc. but Soret effect, Dufour effect instead of Soret's effect, Dufour's effect? What is the principle?

Comment: Just convention. Laws get possessed, but effects are differentiated by noun adjuncts.

Comment: Related: [Saxon genitive to identify algorithms, methods, techniques, theorems](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187894) and [“{somebody}'s theme” vs “{somebody} theme” — Saxon genitive dilemma](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142126).

Comment: It's ***The** Dufour effect/Soret effect/McGurk effect*. Definite noun compounds need definite articles, and proper names are almost always definite. Possessives, on the other hand, are determiners already and can't co-occur with articles: _*The Fourier's Law_, _*the Harry's sister_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, to see a minor exception to the  “Possessives can't co-occur with articles” rule, type *the donald's daughter* into a google search box and pictures of  Ivanka Trump and Tiffany Trump will appear.

Comment: That's not an article; that's part of a proper name: _The Donald._

Comment: Note that this is not specific to laws/effects named for people; laws are generally either "X's law" or "the law of foo" (or "X's law of foo"), whereas effects are generally either "the X effect" or "the foo effect" (or "the X foo effect").

Comment: I have one more question to be sure: [Arrhenius' law](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19780068638), [Arrhenius's law](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/engineering-and-technology/engineering/engineering-the-challenge-temperature/content-section-4.3.1) or [Arrhenius law](http://ch302.cm.utexas.edu/kinetics/temp-depend/selector.php?name=arrhenius-law)?

Comment: @mc2: The "rule" I go by is as follows: If adding an additional S at the end of a possessive word creates a difficult-to-pronounce word, don't add the S and leave the apostrophe. So for example, I opt for Moses' and not Moses's, or Jesus' and not Jesus's. Arrhenius's isn't that much of a tongue twister, at least for me. I don't think a grammarian will slap the back of your wrist with a ruler for writing it Arrhenius', however--though I could be wrong! Don

Comment: Give "Soret effect" a little more time; say, a couple hundred years. Who knows, it might just become a law. Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only authority I've been able to find on this particular question is *The Oxford Style Manual* (2003), which provides this summary:

> **12.1.6 Eponymic designations**
>
> Names identified with specific individuals may be treated in several ways. Traditionally a disease, equation, formula, hypothesis, law, principle, rule, syndrome, theorem, or theory named after a person is preceded by the person’s name followed by an apostrophe and an s [examples omitted]; ... An apparatus, coefficient angle, constant, cycle, effect, function, number, phenomenon, process, reagent, synthesis, or field of study named after a person is usually preceded by the name alone or its adjectival form [examples omitted]. Eponymic anatomical or botanical parts may incorporate the name either as a possessive [examples omitted] or adjectivally [examples omitted]. Something named after two or more people is known by the bare surnames, joined by an en rule [examples omitted].

Regrettably the Oxford manual doesn't explain how this distribution of possessive and nonpossessive forms arose. Bu clearly *Fourier's law*, *Ohm's law*, and *Newton's (various) laws* fall into the traditional "disease, equation, formula, hypothesis, law, principle, rule, syndrome, theorem, or theory" group, while *Soret effect* and *Dufour effect* fall into the traditional "apparatus, coefficient angle, constant, cycle, effect, function, number, phenomenon, process, reagent, synthesis, or field of study" category.

Eponymic designations of diseases and syndromes, however, are rapidly moving out of the former category and into the latter, according to Oxford. I hope to examine this phenomenon shortly in another question.

As for your follow-up question about the law of Arrhenius, the same section of *The Oxford Style Manual* says this:

> any variation follows the normal rules governing possessives (*Charles's law*, *Descartes's rule of signs*, *Archimedes' principle*, *Chagas's disease*, *Fajan's rules*) [cross-reference omitted].

Why the lack of an *s* after the apostrophe in *Archimedes' principle*? *The Oxford Style Manual* again (at 5.2.1):

> Use an apostrophe alone after classical [such as *Demosthenes*] or classicizing [such as *John Duns Scotus*] names ending in *s* ...

*Arrhenius* may sound like a classicized name, but it's actually the last name that Svante August Arrhenius (1859–1927) of Sweden was born with. Therefore, the approved (by Oxford) way to handle the name of of his eponymic law is "Arrhenius's law."