# Why it is "Okun's Law" and "Philips Curve" rather than "Okun Law" and "Philips' Curve"?

Tags: nouns, possessives, compounds

How exactly do these kinds of compound words work?

> "Okun's Law" and "Philips Curve" rather than "Okun Law" and "Philips' Curve"?

Is there any grammar book I can look for?

Comment: Also see *[Why do we write “Fourier's law” but “Soret effect”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199401)*

Comment: Hey, everyone, how is it fair to "equate" Fourier's law with Soret effect, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule, different writers choose different styles. Without moving from my desk I can find the following examples of references to the same thing:

1. Bayes Rule
2. Bayes' Rule
3. Bayes's Rule

and then the same all over again but calling it a theorem rather than a rule.

If the proper name is not in a possessive form, then sometimes the definite article is used, as in "The Bayes Rule" but even that is not standardised.